# What are the benefits of using lambda, function and optional here?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

Today I saw the following code snippet which uses lambdas, optionals and functions in Java for rendering a specific endpoint response. **Is the usage of this function, lambda and of that optional really needed and justified here? What are the benefits?**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/User", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getBySomeAttribute(@RequestParam(value = "someAttribute", required = true) String someAttribute,
                                 HttpServletResponse response) {
    User user = service.getBySomeAttribute(someAttribute);
    return createResponse(user, response);
}

private String createResponse(User user, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String responseBody = maybe((User u) -> {
        response.setStatus(SC_OK);
        return toJsonString(userJsonMapper.jsonMapFrom(u));
    }).apply(user).orElse("");

    setResponseHeaders(response, responseBody.length());
    return responseBody;
}

private Function<User, Optional<String>> maybe(Function<User, String> f) {
    return (u) -> {
        String s = null;
        if (u != null && u.getEnabled()) {
            s = f.apply(u);
        }
        return s != null ? of(s) : Optional.empty();
    };
}

private void setResponseHeaders(HttpServletResponse response, int responseBodySize) {
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", valueOf(responseBodySize));
    response.setHeader("Expires", "1");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
}
```

Comment: It's indeed questionable as there's really no need for delayed execution here (that's the function part)... But answers to this question can only be opinions...

Comment: If the method `maybe` is used only once, this is overly complicated. Looks like a code that was copy/pasted without understanding what it does.

Comment: This is garbage. There are [no benefits](https://ideone.com/UH7e2z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any reason to do almost any of that.  The code provided appears to be equivalent to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/User", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getBySomeAttribute(@RequestParam(value = "someAttribute", required = true) String someAttribute,
                                HttpServletResponse response) {
    User user = service.getBySomeAttribute(someAttribute);
    return createResponse(user, response);
}

private String createResponse(User user, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String responseBody = "";
    if(user != null && user.getEnabled()) {
        String responseBody = toJsonString(userJsonMapper.jsonMapFrom(user))
        response.setStatus(SC_OK);
    }

    setResponseHeaders(response, responseBody.length());
    return responseBody;
}

private void setResponseHeaders(HttpServletResponse response, int responseBodySize) {
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", valueOf(responseBodySize));
    response.setHeader("Expires", "1");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
}
```

But the above is (in my opinion) a hell of a lot easier to read, understand, and maintain.  Unless that lambda is getting some widespread use elsewhere, I can't see a reason for it to exist.  And honestly, it's probably overkill even if it *is* being used elsewhere.